# Allow data input on static site

Tags: php, sql, xml, content-management-system, flat-file

I'm developing a new website. This site has no backend/CMS, but I need to allow an "administrator" to update some data for some svg graphs. I'm thinking I could simply pull in a spreadsheet or xml file, but I'm trying to think of something a little more polished for the client. This got me looking into flatfile cms which could work, but thought id see if anyones else has some good ideas.

Please let me know if your got any suggestions. There will be 5 different graphs all with dynamic data numerical points.

Comment: The "administrator" will have to edit the files on the server if it's a static site.

Comment: Maybe, but it could be pulled from googleDocs or something therfore its not on the server.

Answer (score 0):

One option might be;

- Store the chart data in a .txt
- On the chart display page, where the chart data would have been manually placed before, read/file_get_contents that .txt file in display so it's all in the same format, but the raw data is grabbed from the text file
- Create a simple hidden admin page/form, which has a textarea field with the value of that current chart data .txt file
- When they update it, overwrite the old chart data .txt file with the new textarea input
- And ofcourse secure that admin form with a simple required password field, even though the URL shouldn't be an obvious one like /admin.php -- Keep it flat file by adding failed login IP attempts to another text file. Maybe run a cron every 15-30min to clear that login attempt file.

There's probably much better ways to go about this but that was just off the top of my head, I prefer just using a database though!

Comment: Thanks for your input. Its definitley an option. A nice simple password protected input page.